# Question on Joint Posterior

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo

Likelihood: $f(x^T, n^T|\theta^T) =  \prod_{i=1}^{30} \binom{n^T_i}{x^T_i}{\theta^T}^{x^T_i}{(1-\theta^T)}^{n^T_i-x^T_i}$

Prior: $ log(\frac{\theta^T}{1-\theta^T})\sim N(\mu_T,\sigma_T^2) $

I am required to write a MCMC script with the single site random walk metropolis scheme in R based on the above.

My questions:

1. How can I get the joint posterior from the given distributions?
2. Is it possible to find the distribution of $\theta^T$ ?

Comment: Re 1., do you know the general formula for the posteror in terms of the prior and the likelihood? Re 2., you have the distribution of $\log(\theta/(1-\theta))$, what is stopping you to compute the distribution of $\theta$?

Comment: Hi Did, I was taught that the probability distribution function (pdf) of the posterior is proportional to the product of the pdfs of the prior and the likelihood. For Q2, I thought of finding the moment generating function of $\theta$ but as we know, the lognormal distribution does not have a moment generating function.

Comment: Re 1., then do the product and see what happens. Re 2., to go from a distribution to moments to moments a the transformed random variable to its distribution seems like a *détour*. And here there are no moments, as you noticed. Don't you know a more direct way to determine a distribution?

Answer (score 1):

One is given the likelihood, that is, the distribution of $(X,N)$ conditionally on $T$. The prior, that is, the distribution of $T$, is characterized by the distribution of $R=\log(T/(1-T))$. The posterior is the distribution of $(X,N,T)$.

Let $p$, $f$, $g$, and $h$ denote the densities of the posterior, the likelihood, $T$, and $R$ respectively. Given
$f(x,n\mid \theta)$ and $h(r)$, one asks for $p(x,n,\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ (more rigorously, given $f$ and $h$, one asks for $p$ and $g$). By definition,
$$
p(x,n,\theta)=f(x,n\mid\theta)g(\theta),
$$
hence it remains to compute $g$. Recall that, again by definition, $g$ is characterized by the fact that, for every test function $u$,
$$
E[u(T)]=\int u(\theta)g(\theta)\mathrm d\theta,
$$
and that, still by definition, $h$ is characterized by the fact that, for every test function $v$,
$$
E[v(R)]=\int v(r)h(r)\mathrm dr.
$$
But $E[v(R)]=E[u(T)]$ with $u:\theta\mapsto v(\log(\theta/(1-\theta)))$ hence
one looks for a density $g$ such that, for every test function $v$,
$$
\int v(r)h(r)\mathrm dr=\int v(\log(\theta/(1-\theta))g(\theta)\mathrm d\theta.
$$
The change of variable $r=\log(\theta/(1-\theta))$, $\mathrm dr=\mathrm d\theta/(\theta(1-\theta))$ yields
$$
g(\theta)=\frac{h(\log(\theta/(1-\theta))}{\theta(1-\theta)}.
$$
At this point, one might recognize a Jacobian and be reminded of the [change of variable formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: hi Did, sorry I took some time to reply - was trying to figure out your input. May I know what is the identity called when you equate $E[v(R)] = E[u(t)]$ ? Your answer was really helpful, thank you very much. Sadly, I am unable to contribute to your rep.

Comment: $E[v(R)]=E[u(T)]$ because $v(R)=u(T)$ **for this function $u$**.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now! I was confused because the expectations are with respect to different distributions. So, the change of variable actually takes care of that, correct me if I am wrong. Thank you very much for answering all my doubts, I wish there was a way I could show my gratitude.